# Swift: Threading Issue With DismissViewController() and Dismissing Keyboard

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I'm send some data up to my server, and upon a response, I dismiss my view controller. In the viewController's viewWillDisappear() I attempt to dismiss the keyboard.

If the presentER viewController is not the root view controller, I receive the exception "[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'". I have tried to call a function that dismissed the keyboard then the viewcontroller (removing the need for viewwilldisappear()) but it has the same issue.

Code:
    //within presented viewcontroller

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
    {
            super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
            self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Code:
//within presentER viewcontroller

```
func manage_response(//)
    {
            run_on_background_thread
            {
                    self.parse(//)
                    run_on_main_thread
                    {
                          self.presented_controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

                    }
            }
    }
```

Everything I've seen has indicating this is how to handle the situation. The problem only exists when I have a keyboard displayed and am trying to dismiss it with it's respective viewcontroller.

Edit:

Syntax for trailing method functions I use for threading:

```
func run_on_background_thread(code: () -> Void)
{
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), code)
}

func run_on_main_thread(code: () -> Void)
{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), code)
}
```

Solution:

I've tracked the issue down. The case is different than earlier thought. This occurs when I am trying to display a UIAlertController (via presentViewController) because the query did not return proper data / credentials.

```
run_on_main_thread
            {
                    if let controller = visibleViewController() //recursive
                    {
                            controller.view.endEditing(true)
                            controller.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Where are run_on_background_thread and run_on_main_thread defined?

Comment: My bad. They are defined globally in a file of helper / convenience functions. Included now. Note: they work completely fine throughout the rather complex application, only when the keyboard should be dismissed as well to things go awry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was displaying a UIAlertViewController. This logic/code will resolve such issue:

```
run_on_main_thread
{
    if let controller = visibleViewController() //recursive
    {
         controller.view.endEditing(true)       
         controller.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to dismiss it in main queue this way :

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     self.presented_controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}`

Comment: I do exactly that, which gives me the exception.

Comment: Even if you use instead of dispatch_async, dispatch_sync?

Comment: There are many cons with dispatch_sync; when working with UI, generally many updates will be occuring asynchroniously and so I personally consider this bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right general idea, but what you've posted is pseudo-code. The devil is in the details. If you are getting that error message then somewhere your code is making UIKit calls from a background thread.

NSThread has a class method isMainThread(). You can use that to check to see what code is being run from the background.

Comment: just the arguments of manage_response() and parse() are ommitted. I'll update with trailing function calls I use for the run_on_main_thread and run_on_background_thread

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a wrong assumption somewhere. You've got a completion block that you think is being executed on the main thread but it's not, it's being run on a BG thread. In that completion block you're doing UI code. The damage is already done, and the code you are posting is not the source of the problem. use a call to `NSThread.isMainThread()` all in all your completion blocks/handlers to see what code is running on the main thread and what is not.

Comment: I've tracked the issue down. The case is different than earlier thought. This occurs when I am trying to display a UIAlertController (via presentViewController) because the query did not return proper data / credentials.

run_on_main_thread
                {
                        if let controller = visibleViewController() //recursive
                        {
                                controller.view.endEditing(true)
                                controller.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                }

Comment: If you've solved your problem you should post an answer to your question and accept it.